# I get a different date

Tags: javascript

I need date format like : `2018-10-04T20:35:28.` in javascript.
I don't know what format is this, but I already try follow

Now I have this:

```
var now = new Date();
var isoDate = new Date(now).toISOString();
```

My output is:

```
2018-10-05T04:55:58.896Z
```

But I have a wrong day because actual date is:

> Thu  4 Oct 2018 22:56:53 CST

Why i have +1 day in all dates.

Comment: The ISO string is in UTC, the one in console is in your local time zone. Notice the hour difference.

Comment: `2018-10-05T04:55:58.896Z` ... `Z` == `Zulu` == `GMT` == `UTC` - your timezone is `UTC-6` ... 04:55 on 5/10/2018 UTC is 22:55 on 4/10/2018 in Guatemala

Comment: See also [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for the date format.

Comment: Thank you for your answers .I understood the differences.

Answer (score 0):

like @Nisarg Shah said "The ISO string is in UTC, the one in console is in your local time zone" . You can change it using this

```
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})
```

Check this out for more information.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: The OP wants an ISO 8601 format date in the local timezone and without timezone. This doesn't really help, since *toLocaleString* creates an implementation dependent string that is typically not ISO 8601.

Comment: There are 6 time zones in US I learned. So a Website that needs to run for American audience, what is the solution?  America/New_York will give me new york time zone, so does it mean, If I see the website from san fransico, I will see wrong timing?

Comment: @BILALMALIK— if "wrong" means not in their local timezone, then yes. If you want to format a date using host timezone settings, then format the string as a local timestamp. There are many questions here already on how to do that.

Comment: @RobG Can you clarify me little more on this? Host time zone = where my server is hosted- say it is in Brazil, And I'm browsing from San Francisco with wrong manual timing on the local machine. So are you saying solution = Brazil +- San Francisco time  or San Francisco local machine time, or what? Please explain.

Comment: @BILALMALIK—javascript requires a host to provide the environment for the code to run it, so "host" is the system on which the implementation is running. If your code is running in a browser on a laptop, that's the host. If you use "local" date methods, you'll get the timezone offset for the host system (whatever that might be).

Comment: @RobG - yes I get the point we use the local date method to show the client its local time. Thanks for teaching me "host"? , javascript client side host, website host confuses me so much. Thanks Rob

Answer (score 0):

```
var isoDate = new Date(now).toISOString();

// Output
2018-10-05T04:55:58.896Z
```

This isoDate is in UTC. You can see that there is a 'Z' in the end of the string. This means that the date is in UTC.

You can use Moment Timezone (moment.js) to convert any given date to another timezone.

```
moment.tz('2018-10-05T04:55:58.896Z', 'America/Toronto').format();
```

Just change the timezone name to the one you want to convert.

For Further Details
 https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/